# STM32F407 FSMC interface with TFT LCD

Tags: stm32, lcd, tft, fsmc

I've written some code to make a FSMC connection between my STM32F407VET6 and a TFT LCD 240x320 pixels. I was checking this several times, however I can't recognize what's wrong.
I'm using 16-bit data bus with FSMC_NE1, FSMC_A16, FSMC_NWE, FSMC_NOE. I've connected PE6 pin which is FSMC_A22 in FSMC interface. Now I'm wondering weather it can work with such configuration (I mean PE6 pin). All I get is white screen on my LCD as it is in RESET state.

Here's my code to configure FSMC:

```
    void init_FSMC(void)
{
    GPIO_InitTypeDef GPIO_InitStructure;
    FSMC_NORSRAMInitTypeDef  FSMC_NORSRAMInitStructure;
    FSMC_NORSRAMTimingInitTypeDef FSMC_NORSRAMTimingInitStructure;
    RCC_AHB1PeriphClockCmd(RCC_AHB1Periph_GPIOD, ENABLE);
    RCC_AHB1PeriphClockCmd(RCC_AHB1Periph_GPIOE, ENABLE);
    RCC_AHB3PeriphClockCmd(RCC_AHB3Periph_FSMC, ENABLE);
    GPIO_PinAFConfig(GPIOD, GPIO_PinSource0, GPIO_AF_FSMC);     // D2
    GPIO_PinAFConfig(GPIOD, GPIO_PinSource1, GPIO_AF_FSMC);     // D3
    GPIO_PinAFConfig(GPIOD, GPIO_PinSource4, GPIO_AF_FSMC);     // NOE -> RD
    GPIO_PinAFConfig(GPIOD, GPIO_PinSource5, GPIO_AF_FSMC);     // NWE -> WR
    GPIO_PinAFConfig(GPIOD, GPIO_PinSource7, GPIO_AF_FSMC);     // NE1 -> CS
    GPIO_PinAFConfig(GPIOD, GPIO_PinSource8, GPIO_AF_FSMC);     // D13
    GPIO_PinAFConfig(GPIOD, GPIO_PinSource9, GPIO_AF_FSMC);     // D14
    GPIO_PinAFConfig(GPIOD, GPIO_PinSource10, GPIO_AF_FSMC);    // D15
    GPIO_PinAFConfig(GPIOD, GPIO_PinSource11, GPIO_AF_FSMC);    // A16 -> RS
    GPIO_PinAFConfig(GPIOD, GPIO_PinSource14, GPIO_AF_FSMC);    // D0
    GPIO_PinAFConfig(GPIOD, GPIO_PinSource15, GPIO_AF_FSMC);    // D1
    GPIO_PinAFConfig(GPIOE, GPIO_PinSource7, GPIO_AF_FSMC);     // D4
    GPIO_PinAFConfig(GPIOE, GPIO_PinSource8, GPIO_AF_FSMC);     // D5
    GPIO_PinAFConfig(GPIOE, GPIO_PinSource9, GPIO_AF_FSMC);     // D6
    GPIO_PinAFConfig(GPIOE, GPIO_PinSource10, GPIO_AF_FSMC);    // D7
    GPIO_PinAFConfig(GPIOE, GPIO_PinSource11, GPIO_AF_FSMC);    // D8
    GPIO_PinAFConfig(GPIOE, GPIO_PinSource12, GPIO_AF_FSMC);    // D9
    GPIO_PinAFConfig(GPIOE, GPIO_PinSource13, GPIO_AF_FSMC);    // D10
    GPIO_PinAFConfig(GPIOE, GPIO_PinSource14, GPIO_AF_FSMC);    // D11
    GPIO_PinAFConfig(GPIOE, GPIO_PinSource15, GPIO_AF_FSMC);    // D12
    GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Mode = GPIO_Mode_AF;
    GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_OType = GPIO_OType_PP;
    GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_PuPd = GPIO_PuPd_NOPULL;
    GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Speed = GPIO_Speed_100MHz;
    GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Pin = GPIO_Pin_0 | GPIO_Pin_1 | GPIO_Pin_4 | GPIO_Pin_5 | GPIO_Pin_7 | GPIO_Pin_8 | GPIO_Pin_9 | GPIO_Pin_10 | GPIO_Pin_11 | GPIO_Pin_14 | GPIO_Pin_15;
    GPIO_Init(GPIOD, &GPIO_InitStructure);
    GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Pin = GPIO_Pin_7 | GPIO_Pin_8 | GPIO_Pin_9 | GPIO_Pin_10 | GPIO_Pin_11 | GPIO_Pin_12 | GPIO_Pin_13 | GPIO_Pin_14 | GPIO_Pin_15;
    GPIO_Init(GPIOE, &GPIO_InitStructure);
    FSMC_NORSRAMInitStructure.FSMC_Bank = FSMC_Bank1_NORSRAM1;
    FSMC_NORSRAMInitStructure.FSMC_DataAddressMux = FSMC_DataAddressMux_Disable;
    FSMC_NORSRAMInitStructure.FSMC_MemoryType = FSMC_MemoryType_SRAM;
    FSMC_NORSRAMInitStructure.FSMC_MemoryDataWidth = FSMC_MemoryDataWidth_16b;
    FSMC_NORSRAMInitStructure.FSMC_BurstAccessMode = FSMC_BurstAccessMode_Disable;
    FSMC_NORSRAMInitStructure.FSMC_WaitSignalPolarity = FSMC_WaitSignalPolarity_Low;
    FSMC_NORSRAMInitStructure.FSMC_WrapMode = FSMC_WrapMode_Disable;
    FSMC_NORSRAMInitStructure.FSMC_WaitSignalActive = FSMC_WaitSignalActive_BeforeWaitState;
    FSMC_NORSRAMInitStructure.FSMC_WriteOperation = FSMC_WriteOperation_Enable;
    FSMC_NORSRAMInitStructure.FSMC_WaitSignal = FSMC_WaitSignal_Disable;
    FSMC_NORSRAMInitStructure.FSMC_AsynchronousWait = FSMC_AsynchronousWait_Disable;
    FSMC_NORSRAMInitStructure.FSMC_ExtendedMode = FSMC_ExtendedMode_Disable;
    FSMC_NORSRAMInitStructure.FSMC_WriteBurst = FSMC_WriteBurst_Enable;
    FSMC_NORSRAMInitStructure.FSMC_ReadWriteTimingStruct = &FSMC_NORSRAMTimingInitStructure;
    FSMC_NORSRAMInit(&FSMC_NORSRAMInitStructure);
    FSMC_NORSRAMTimingInitStructure.FSMC_AddressSetupTime = 1;      
    FSMC_NORSRAMTimingInitStructure.FSMC_AddressHoldTime = 1;      
    FSMC_NORSRAMTimingInitStructure.FSMC_DataSetupTime = 3;   
    FSMC_NORSRAMTimingInitStructure.FSMC_BusTurnAroundDuration = 0;
    FSMC_NORSRAMTimingInitStructure.FSMC_CLKDivision = 1;
    FSMC_NORSRAMTimingInitStructure.FSMC_DataLatency = 0;
    FSMC_NORSRAMTimingInitStructure.FSMC_AccessMode = FSMC_AccessMode_A;    
    FSMC_NORSRAMInitStructure.FSMC_WriteTimingStruct = &FSMC_NORSRAMTimingInitStructure;
    FSMC_NORSRAMInit(&FSMC_NORSRAMInitStructure);
    FSMC_NORSRAMCmd(FSMC_Bank1_NORSRAM1, ENABLE);
}
```

I'm using this address to write commands and data:

```
#define LCD_REG      (*((volatile unsigned short *) 0x60000000)) 
#define LCD_RAM      (*((volatile unsigned short *) 0x60020000)) 
LCD_RAM = data;
LCD_REG = command;
```

I have no idea what I am doing wrong. I know there is several similar topics, however none of them help with this issue. I'm trying to cope with that problem for several weeks - with no results.

I'm out of my mind... and don;t know to do next.

Thanks for any help

Comment: I've reused your code on an 8 bit LCD (but had to convert it to use the HAL) & it almost works. I can see the control lines jiggling about but if I try to write twice, on the 2nd time, I get a hard fault. Trying to figure out why.

Answer (score 4):

I've found the answer!
I missed the fact I didn't configurate a PE6 pin as ordinary GPIO output thus I couldn't reset my LCD.